# Search results customization in Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template, shopify-storefront-api

I have a store in Shopify. Currently if I use the Shopify search feature, it only enables people to search for the title of either blogs, pages or products.
For Eg: If I search for a term "healthy scalp", it will only display the pages, blogs or products which has that term in the title, but I also need to display pages which has those keywords in the description or content of the pages.

Is there a way to do it through code or any app?

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thanks!

I tried to check the settings in the Shopify Admin panel as well as the theme(Prestige) settings but did not find any option to do that.

I also checked the code but hard luck!